# 3D World coords to on-screen coords in an ancient engine

Tags: c#

I've been googling for past 2 hours and I couldn't find a satisfying solution that wouldn't require you to use Unity, OpenGL or Unreal Engine.

My issue is, I was given a task to make a game on an ancient 3D engine built purely from scratch (no OpenGL etc.).

The task I was given is - draw text above every chest the player can see.

In OpenGL I would do a simple transformation seeing how I've got all what I need built in, but in here I have to do the math myself.

The game from top-down looks like this:
[image]

Hearts represent chestboxes, the rest is marked.

So here's what I know for sure that might be useful:

- I know XYZ positions of these hearts
- I know the maximum angle after which chest disappears fully from my sight is -32.5 for the left edge and 32.5 for the right screen edge - which made me conclude that FOV is 75.
- The game window (viewport dimensions) is 1024x768
- I can calculate pitch/yaw easily for any two vectors, be it player->camera, player->chest, camera->chest etc.

What I don't know is - where do I go from there?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

PS: The language I'm allowed to write in is C#, but I'm only looking for help with formula so.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the same thing as you would do using OpenGL or DirectX. Simply create a projection matrix using the fov and resolution, then get the coordinates of the chests relative to the camera (which you can get by multiplying the positions of them by the view matrix) and finally multiply these two together to get the screen coordinates of those objects.